# reactjs application add to existing reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting out in Reactjs.

I have a RedHat Linux VM.

I've installed nodejs and created a simple reactjs application:

```
npx create-react-app my-first-project
```

My first project works OK.

Now I have found this great reactjs package with a demo:

```
https://github.com/TarikHuber/material-ui-filter
```

I want to install the demo part of this package that consists of index.css, index.html, app.js, index.js

How would I go with this?
Where do I put this new code relative to my-first-project?
How do I call this new code?
The package I think calls redux so I assume I will install this first.

Thanks.

Comment: I checked this github repo. There's a well defined README.md attached with it. Make sure you're following that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how npm works. If you find some cool package and you want to use it then you have to install that package. There is a installation command on Readme file on that github repo. Install package via `npm install material-ui-filter` then you can just use the html file on demo project.